# Smooth Click-to-Zoom function working on some markers but not others

Tags: javascript, google-maps

My custom Google Map uses a click listener to zoom in smoothly (ie, one zoom level at a time) on several markers, revealing poly fields for sports game locations. Two of these markers zoom in correctly; the other three zoom all the way in with a single step - jumping from zoom level 11 to 15 instantly. Other click events fire normally.

I've tried to move my click listener and for loop function to different sections of my code (within my marker constructor function and outside of it). This either made no change to functionality if moved around within the constructor function, or resulted in formatting errors that broke the entire script.

I also changed the variable in my for loop from the traditional 'i' to 'z' in case there was some kind of interference with the parent for loop (also using 'i'). Note: I am an inexperienced javascript user so I have no idea if this is relevant or if each for loop is completely self-contained, variable name wise.

```
        var marker, i;
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]),
                title: markers[i][0],
                label: {
                    text: markers[i][0],
                    fontSize: "12px",
                    fontWeight: "bold"
                },
                map: map,
                icon: markerIcon,
                calURL: markers[i][3]
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
                for (z = 1; z < 16; z++) {
                    map.setZoom(z)
                }
                var calsec = document.getElementById('capture');

                calsec.innerHTML = this.calURL;


            });
```

The array of arrays used to construct the markers is as follows:

```
    markers = [
            ['Parkinson Sports Fields', 49.88264, -119.46045, '<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?mode=AGENDA&amp;height=500&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=blackbeancreative.com_mgj0i3q12ang1as82p8ggf3fuc%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23691426&amp;ctz=America%2FVancouver" style="border-width:0" width="500" height="500" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>'],
            ['Rutland Sports Fields', 49.89953, -119.38019, '<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?mode=AGENDA&amp;height=500&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=blackbeancreative.com_mgj0i3q12ang1as82p8ggf3fuc%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23691426&amp;ctz=America%2FVancouver" style="border-width:0" width="500" height="500" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>'],
            ['Mission Sports Fields', 49.83979, -119.47623, '<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?mode=AGENDA&amp;height=500&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=blackbeancreative.com_mgj0i3q12ang1as82p8ggf3fuc%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23691426&amp;ctz=America%2FVancouver" style="border-width:0" width="500" height="500" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>'],
            ['Rosewood Sports Field', 49.87567, -119.56956, '<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?mode=AGENDA&amp;height=500&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=blackbeancreative.com_mgj0i3q12ang1as82p8ggf3fuc%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23691426&amp;ctz=America%2FVancouver" style="border-width:0" width="500" height="500" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>'],
            ['Shannon Woods Sports Field', 49.8669, -119.60595, '<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?mode=AGENDA&amp;height=500&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=blackbeancreative.com_mgj0i3q12ang1as82p8ggf3fuc%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23691426&amp;ctz=America%2FVancouver" style="border-width:0" width="500" height="500" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>']
        ];
```

The two which work are 'Parkinson Sports Fields' and 'Mission Sports Fields'. The rest instantly zoom. I considered that it may have something to do with the map's default viewport, which is centered at 49.876837, -119.461071. This point is closer to Parkinson and Mission than the other fields.

Comment: Which markers don't work?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (in the question itself, preferably a stackoverflow code snippet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should anyone happen to find this and have a similar issue, I did figure out a fix.

```
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
                var latitude = event.latLng.lat();
                var longitude = event.latLng.lng();
                console.log(latitude);
                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude));

                setTimeout(function() {


                    for (z = 1; z < 16; z++) {
                        map.setZoom(z)

                    }
                }, 100);
```

The setCenter line I had originally added wasn't properly grabbing the latlng object for the clicked marker. Rebuilding the event listener as seen above properly grabs both values then builds a latlng object from them. Adding a short timeout to the zoom function gives the map time to recenter itself, which seems to help with the smoothness of the zoom.

The reason why smooth zoom worked for some markers and not for others was because the setCenter function was failing. The markers closest to the map origin were able to zoom smoothly, while markers further from the origin weren't able to zoom without re-centering the map.